# SoapFormatter in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, soap, xml-serialization

How should I migrate the following c# 4.8 framework to .NET Core 3.1 ?

Code is:

```
public enum E { V }
[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public E my_enum;
    public bool my_bool;
}
[...]
Person p = new Person();
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("myfile.soap", FileMode.Create))
{
    SoapFormatter f = new SoapFormatter();
    f.Serialize(fs, p);
    fs.Close();
}
```

Give me the expected:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:clr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/soap/encoding/clr/1.0" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<a1:Person id="ref-1" xmlns:a1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/ConsoleApp/ConsoleApp%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull">
<my_enum>V</my_enum>
<my_bool>false</my_bool>
</a1:Person>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

After reading:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-serialize-an-object-as-a-soap-encoded-xml-stream

and:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/attributes-that-control-encoded-soap-serialization

and also:

- https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/15352

I tried:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Person p = new Person();
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("myfile.soap", FileMode.Create))
    {
        XmlTypeMapping myTypeMapping = new SoapReflectionImporter()
          .ImportTypeMapping(typeof(Person));
        XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(myTypeMapping);
        mySerializer.Serialize(fs, p);
        fs.Close();
    }
}
```

Which gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="id1">
  <my_enum xsi:type="E">V</my_enum>
  <my_bool xsi:type="xsd:boolean">false</my_bool>
</Person>
```

Comment: I said in previous posting the "xsi:type" is being added because of your inherited class.

Answer (score 1):

It depends which parts you're trying to fix; if it is the namespaces: *tell `XmlSerializer` about them*:

```cs
// note: this would be [XmlType(...)] if it wasn't the root element
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/ConsoleApp/ConsoleApp%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull")]
public class Person
{
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public E my_enum;
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public bool my_bool;
}
```

If it is the namespace-alias (although that doesn't change the meaning):

```cs
XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("a1", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/clr/nsassem/ConsoleApp/ConsoleApp%2C%20Version%3D1.0.0.0%2C%20Culture%3Dneutral%2C%20PublicKeyToken%3Dnull");
XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
mySerializer.Serialize(fs, p, ns);
```

If it is the wrapper nodes: you'll need to add those, perhaps via types, perhaps manually as fixup.

However, fundamentally `XmlSerializer` and `SoapFormatter` are not 1:1 interchangeable, and you shouldn't attempt to make them so. Honestly, it would be safer to think of it as a fundamental serialization switch, than to try and hack it until it kinda-sorta works.

Comment: Thanks ! I'll check if I can read legacy SoapFormatter serialized data in my new app using your solution.